# Converting coördinates into addresses

Tags: php, sql

I created a database, which contains many locations expressed in longitude and latitude. How can I convert them automitcally into addresses? (Reverse Geocoding)For this task I want to use PHP and SQL, because I am building a webapplication.

Comment: `$address = address_from_lonlat($longitude, $latitude)`... of course, you get to implement that function.

Comment: Something you should consider is that this task is impossible for an arbitrary set of coordinates: what if you have a point in the middle of the ocean? Or even somewhere like Antarctica where (I presume) there aren't any addresses?

Anyway, my best guess is that there is some API somewhere that will do this. I'll try to find one.

Comment: All the coördinates that I've got belong to addresses, because it's data of starts and stops from taxi's.

Comment: The function address_from_lonlat($longitude, latitude) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Map API can do this.

Example:

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latitude.",".$longitude."&sensor=false&key=".$API_KEY));
```

You can see the kind of response you'll get on the page about [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). In the above example, I parsed the JSON response string into an appropriate php object.

Comment: I get the following error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Oh whoops, I shouldn't have said it's an array. I assume your error is surfacing when you try to `echo`/`print_r` your `$response`. Instead, try using `var_dump($response)`. Edited my answer.